# Google Chrome Tabs Execute Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a google chrome extension that scrape out specific data from the page once the page is finished loading. I'm trying to achieve it by executing a javascript file by setting `file : 'js/scrape.js'` and `runAt: 'document_idle'`.

However, setting `selected : false` does work but `selected : true` doesn't.

index.js:

```
var crawler = function() {
return {
    init : function() {
        document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', this.open);
    },
    open : function() {
        var url = document.getElementById('url').value;

        chrome.tabs.create({
            url : url,
            selected : true //doesn't work, setting to false does work
        }, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file : 'js/scrape.js',
                runAt : 'document_idle'
            });
        });
    }
}}()
```

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    crawler.init();
});`

I included `index.js` inside popup.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Finally, manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Crawler",
"description": "Scrape out the crap.",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Scrape out the crap",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

}

Comment: `selected` is deprecated. Try using `active` instead.

Comment: I read a couple of docs online how come these were not get updated? Anyways, thanks!

Comment: No idea but the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) has the value pretty clearly marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `active => true` fixed the issue. I missed the part of the documentation that explains it.